# How to add user control to panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have created multiple user controls in my project and what I need to do is to be able to switch between them on a panel control.

for example, if the user click button1, userControl1 will be added to panel after removing every control on it and so on.

I have this code :

```
panel1.Controls.Add(MyProject.Modules.Masters);
```

but it's not working.

How I can do it?

Comment: Is `MyProject.Modules.Masters` the Control's class name or an instance of the Control?

Comment: MyProject.Modules.Masters is the Control's class name

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to instantiate your controls. You will have to make sure the size is set appropriately, or for it to have an appropriate dockfill.

```
var myControl = new MyProject.Modules.Masters();
panel1.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

Comment: the best way. thank you

Answer (score 11):

You need to instantiate a new MyProject.Modules.Masters.

```
MyProject.Modules.Masters myMasters = new MyProject.Modules.Masters()
panel1.Controls.Add(myMasters);
```

This will only add a new control to panel1. If you also want to clear everything out of the panel before adding the control like you said in the question, call this first:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't just easier.

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
panel1.Controls.Add(new MyProject.Modules.Masters());
```

EDIT: Maybe try this...

```
panel1.Controls.Cast<Control>().ForEach(i => i.Dispose());
panel1.Controls.Clear();
panel1.Controls.Add(new MyProject.Modules.Masters());
```

Comment: Controls.Clear will not dispose of those existing controls.