# c# Draw Textbox onclick

Tags: c#, textbox, draw

For a project at school I need to create a program called Use Case Helper.

When I click somewhere in the windows form application, a textbox must appear. I don't know how I can achieve this, I think with a paint event, but i couldn't find anything.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should examine OnClick event on your Form or Panel. Then you should get x and y parameters and, finally, use method `panel1.Controls.Add(yourTextBox);`
But seriously, this is googleable question, so, please, avoid asking such on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I couldn't find the solution on google though

Comment: Seriously? Just a quick search:
How to get mouse position on click c#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055211/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-click

How to add control on panel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763228/how-to-add-user-control-to-panel

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = "Sample Stuff";

        tb.Location = e.Location;

        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
```

This will add a textbox wherever you click.